# There any way to differentiate a md5 of a sha-1?

Tags: md5, hash, sha1

I want to know if there exists a way to differentiate a md5 hashcode of a sha-1 hashcode?

For example:

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709

How could I know which are encrypted in md5 and which are not? Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking, but MD5 is 128 bits/32 hex digits, while SHA-1 is 160 bits/40 hex digits, so it's fairly easy to tell the difference between them (providing, of course, that you know that your hashes will be either MD5 or SHA-1 and not something else).

(If you're asking whether you can determine if a given MD5 hash is a hash of a hash or a hash of some other data, then I believe the answer is "no".)

Answer (score 4):

MD5 gives a 128-bit hash value.

SHA-1 gives a 160-bit hash value.